# I got these errors while compiling this c program

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
#include<stdio.h>
  main()
  {
     int num1,num2,sum;
     printf("Enter the two integers to be added");
     scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
     sum = num1+num2;
     printf("Addition of %d and %d = %d", num1, num2, sum);
  }
```

The errors I get are:

> 1. Unable to open include file 'stdio.h'
> 2. Function printf should have a prototype.
> 3. Function scanf should have a prototype.

Comment: can be a problem with your  installation. Check if the file stdio.h is present in the directory.If not Get the file form the link <http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/21762bb4a1bd0c88c38eead03f59e8d994349e83/tree/include/stdio.h>

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but the `main` has to be defined as `int main()` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: How are you compiling?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "unable to open stdio.h in Turbo C" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356687/how-to-fix-unable-to-open-stdio-h-in-turbo-c-error)

Comment: The big problem here is that the preprocessor cannot find stdio.h.  On unix systems (Linux, *BSD, Solaris, etc), the file is usually located in /usr/include.  As someone pointed out, this may be a problem with your installation.  Check your include paths and make sure that everything is on it that should be on it.  The other two errors are generally warnings and are a result of a missing stdio.h file.

Comment: Like everybody else has pointed out: `Unable to open include file 'stdio.h'` definitely sounds like an install problem.  Re-install, and try again.  If it *still* doesn't work, please post back 1) which compiler you're using (MSVS? GCC?  "Something else"?), 2) which platform you're running (DOS?  Linux?  Mac?  "something else"?), and 3) how you're compiling (from a command line?  An IDE?)

Comment: PS: "get stdio.h from the link" is *BAD ADVICE*.  I would *NOT* download a copy of "stdio.h" from MinGW, for example, and expect it to work with MSVS.  "stdio.h" should absolutely come installed with the specific compiler - and compiler version - you're actually using.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have installed the c compiler properly. If you are on linux OS then it comes pre-installed.

Comment: There is no such single thing as "linux OS", and indeed many Linux distributions do not install a compiler by default.